# document.CreateElement Implementation

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xml-parsing

I need some help with JavaScript. As while i was working on use of XML with JavaScript , i have come through lots of problem. So i want to use `document.createElement("ul")` `document.createElement("ul")` instead of `var html = "<li>" + node.nodeName;`in my program.As i need to give a proper style and and need to give some events Attached. So i need some help. I am attaching a live Fiddle of my program which i am working with.

### [Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsZS8/)

```
function generate(node) {
    if (node.nodeType != 1) return "";
    var html = "<li>" + node.nodeName;
    var htmlForChildNodes = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        htmlForChildNodes += generate(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
    if (htmlForChildNodes) {
        html += "<ul>" + htmlForChildNodes + "</ul>";
    }
    html += "</li>";
    return html;
}
```

---

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure exactly what you want, but this example use `createElement`:

```
function generate(node) {
    if (node.nodeType != 1) return "";
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = node.nodeName;
    span.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.target.parentNode.classList.toggle("selected");
    });    
    li.appendChild(span);

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var r = generate(node.childNodes[i]); 
        if(r!==""){
            ul.appendChild(r);
        }
    }
    li.appendChild(ul);   
    return li;
}

if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
} else { // Internet Explorer
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
}

var masterUL = document.createElement('ul');
masterUL.appendChild(generate(xmlDoc.documentElement));
document.body.appendChild(masterUL);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nsZS8/3/)